# loop through text files in batch file

Tags: windows, oracle

using below batch script to check for some info from the listed databases. Passing db details through Dbinfo.txt file.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (Dbinfo.txt) do sqlplus -s username/password@%%i @script.sql >>somelogfile.txt
```

Seems like batch script is not progressing after first line execution as am getting output for one database. Is there any problem with above batch script?

Comment: You're almost certainly missing a CALL.

    ... do call sqlplus -s u...

Comment: Does not seems like working with call..                               for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (Dbinfo.txt) do call sqlplus -s username/password@%%i @script.sql >>somelogfile.txt